# Datasweet Metric on Amazon Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, aws-elasticsearch, kibana-7

We have AWS elastic search and Amazon Kibana. Do we have Datasweet metric available on Amazon Kibana

Datasweet is the external plugin. I'm not sure if we can import external plugins to Amazon Kibana.

I've already tried Scripted fields on Kibana. However, I'm unable to perform '/' and if conditions, It is also creating columns on elastic search cluster.

Is there any option to perform % calculation on Amazon Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import external plugins on Amazon managed Kibana. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html) is the list of supported plugins from AWS documentation.

In case you need to have this plugin, a workaround would be to install Kibana in an EC2 instance and point it towards AWS Elasticsearch. In this case, you would have to manage your custom Kibana installation.